# Error messages upon form validation should be hidden

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I have a question regarding form validation using codeigniter. After a user presses the "submit" button they are getting the intended error messages but I'm also getting a error message (below). The values that are displaying the error messages are hidden. I don't believe that's the culprit because I tried the syntax without the values being hidden and it didn't work. What am I doing wrong? Thanks everyone.

Error messages

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: id
Filename: views/view_information.php
Line Number: 46
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: year
Filename: views/view_information.php
Line Number: 48
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: make
Filename: views/view_information.php
Line Number: 49
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: model
Filename: views/view_information.php
Line Number: 50
```

My View

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    label{display: block}
</style>

<?php
    echo (isset($error)) ? $error : "";
    if(isset($carprices) && !is_null($carprices))
    {
        echo "Car# " . $carprices[0]->id . "<br />";
        foreach ($carprices as $prices)
        {
            echo 'ID Of Vehicle: '.$prices->id.'<br>';
            echo 'Year: '.$prices->year.'<br>';
            echo 'Make: '.$prices->make.'<br>';
            echo 'Model: '.$prices->model.'<br>';
            echo '<hr>';

            $id = $prices->id;
            $year = $prices->year;
            $make = $prices->make;
            $model = $prices->model;
            echo "$id".'<br>';
        }
    }

    /*
        foreach($updateprices as $row){
            $id = $row->id;
            $year = $row->year;
            $make = $row->make;
            $model = $row->model;
        }
    */

    echo form_open('site/form_validate_cars'); 
    echo validation_errors();

    $data = array(
        'cardescription_id'    => "$id",
        'caruser_id' => "5", // hard-coded in
        'year'  => "$year",
        'make'  => "$make",
        'model' => "$model"
    );

    echo form_hidden($data);

    echo form_label('Value:','value');

    $data = array(
        'name' => 'value',
        'id' => 'value',
        'value' => set_value('value')
    );

    echo form_input($data);

    // -----------------

    echo form_label('Exterior Color:','exterior_color');

    $data = array(
        'name' => 'exterior_color',
        'id' => 'exterior_color',
        'value' => set_value('exterior_color')
    );

    echo form_input($data);

    // -----------------

    echo form_label('Interior Color', 'interior_color');

    $data = array(
        'name' => 'interior_color',
        'id' => 'interior_color',
        'value' => set_value('interior_color')
    );

    echo form_input($data);

    // -----------------

    echo form_label('Mileage:','mileage');

    $data = array(
        'name' => 'mileage',
        'id' => 'mileage',
        'value' => set_value('mileage')
    );

    echo form_input($data);

    // -----------------
    // removed echo-only <tr>s on fuel type, state and transmission
    // -----------------

    echo form_label('State:','state');

    $data = array(
        'Texas' => 'Texas',
        'California' => 'California',
        'Florida' => 'Florida',
        'Nevada' => 'Nevada'
    );

    echo form_dropdown('State',$data,'California');
    echo '<br>';
    echo form_submit('SubmitDealerInfo','Submit!');
    echo form_close();
?>
```

Comment: which `LINES` are those?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be like this?

```
foreach ($carprices as $prices)
    {
       echo 'ID Of Vehicle: '.$prices['id'].'<br>';
       echo 'Year: '.$prices['year'].'<br>';
       echo 'Make: '.$prices['make'].'<br>';
       echo 'Model: '.$prices['model'].'<br>';
       echo '<hr>';

       $id = $prices['id'];
       $year = $prices['year'];
       $make = $prices['make'];
       $model = $prices['model'];
       echo "$id".'<br>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not codeigniter validation the problem is with your code
1-check that did you pass all the variables to view when your validation false
2-check your input name is the same as the validation name.

Comment: that is part of the problem. The $id,$year,$make,$model are hidden values. They are not to be validated. How can I have the user validate these values when they aren't suppose to see them in the first place? Please advise. Thanks for your help.